# No Track info after burning CD on Banshee

Tags: banshee

Using Banshee, I ripped songs from a CD and added them to my library.  Then I added the track information to each song, and burned them to a new CD.  The problem is that after doing all of that, the new CD still showed "Unknown" for the all of the songs, artist and album.  I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: This is still the situation with Banshee 2.6.2 (in the age of Ubuntu 16)

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected result.

When you insert a CD, Banshee tries to get track information from a number of online sources (e.g. [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/)). If it can't identify your CD, you get "Unknown" instead.

Adding the track information within Banshee will not make a difference, because you have not changed the online databases. If the CD is not an officially produced CD, then there's nothing you can do about this. However if it is a published CD, you can add the metadata to MusicBrainz. One way to do this is to install *Sound Juicer Audio CD Extractor* from the Software Centre and following the instructions.

[image]

Comment: Sound Juicer as well as Rythmbox are pieces of player software which are able to read the table of contents of a CD, unlike (alas) Banshee. Also Rhythmbox gives the same possibility of augmenting MusicBrainz, so in this respect one might not need install one more program.